# Adding a convolver reverb to an audio file

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm sorry, I'm really a newbie in Javascript and web audio api. I'm trying to add a reverb to an audio file, with the possibility to regulate the amount of the reverb to be added, but the code doesn't work...can you please help me? Thanks a lot in advance!

So thanks to @Raymond Toy, I found the problem in the code. This code now works:

```
   const track1 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement1);
   const playButton1 = document.getElementById('player1');
   const gainNode1 = audioContext.createGain();
   var sub1 = document.getElementById("sub1");
   
   var impulseResponseBuffer;
   var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest ();
   getSound.open("get", "circular.wav", true);
   getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";

   getSound.onload = function () {
       audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) {
          impulseResponseBuffer = buffer;
       });
   };
   getSound.send();

   playButton1.addEventListener('click', function() {
   if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
       audioContext.resume();
   }

   if (this.dataset.playing === 'false') {
       audioElement1.currentTime = 0;
       audioElement1.play();
       audioElement1.loop = 'true';
       this.dataset.playing = 'true';
       var convolver = audioContext.createConvolver();
       convolver.buffer = impulseResponseBuffer;
       track1.connect(convolver);
       convolver.connect(gainNode1);
       gainNode1.connect(audioContext.destination);
       track1.connect(audioContext.destination);
       sub1.innerHTML = "Stop";
   } else if (this.dataset.playing === 'true') {
       audioElement1.pause();
       this.dataset.playing = 'false';
       sub1.innerHTML = "Play";
   }
   }, false);

   audioElement1.addEventListener('ended', () => {
   playButton1.dataset.playing = 'false';
   }, false);

   const volumeControl1 = document.getElementById('volume1');
   
   volumeControl1.addEventListener('input', function() {
       gainNode1.gain.value = this.value;
   }, false);""
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you really need to describe in what way it doesn't work. Is there no sound?  Sound isn't what you expected?  Error messages in the developer console?

Second, consider looking at Figure 2 and Example 2 in [Modular Routing](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#ModularRouting).  There's lot of extraneous things there, but I think what you want is two gain nodes: dry gain and wet gain, where the dry gain is for the audio you're playing (unmodified), and the wet gain is for the output of the convolver.  You an adjust the gains to control how much of the convolver effect is in the final output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your reply! I have no error messages in the console and if I play the button, I hear the sound of the file (only the dry sound). But if I move the slider of the gain (it's the slider that, in theory, should vary the amount of reverb to be added) the sound doesn't change at all.
I could try creating a "dry gain" and "wet gain" as you say, but normally also my structure should work, If I'm not mistaken...

Comment: First, I don't think you should have added this answer.  I think this should have been a comment to my answer.  Second, I'd simplify your test case a lot and just use an OscillatorNode as the source and play around with that until you get things working.  Then plug in the MediaElement you want to play.  Finally, a runnable snippet at jsfiddle or codepen or whatever is nice to make it easier for people to test out your example.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Sorry, it's the first time I write here, I've made a mistake. In any case, I will try to simplify using an oscillator, to check if it works.

Comment: No problem.  Please let us know how the oscillator goes.  I'm curious to see what you come up with and whether it's a problem somewhere else in your code.  In any case, whenever I run into problems like this, I always try to simplify things as much as possible and use Oscillators if I can to test out the logic.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've tried with the oscillator and it was working good...this helped me a lot to find the problem on my code, so now it's working also with the audio file.

Comment: Awesome!  It would be great if you could update this answer with the fixes you needed to make it work so that others will know how to make it work.